# Load an storyboard (UITableViewController) from ViewController

Tags: ios

I want to load an storyboard from a ViewController. Currently my code looks as follows:

```
- (IBAction)Button_Action:(id)sender
{
    UIStoryboard * sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"AddReportView" bundle:nil];
    AddReportViewVC * vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddReportView"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:true];
}
```

The view is pushed but I do not see my expected View Controller (which is a UITableViewController) instead I just see an empty gray view controller.

Comment: You should log vc to make sure it's not nil. I don't see anything wrong with the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that in both the identifier name and the storyboard name, capitalization matters. I've gotten this wrong so many times...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that a function of the generated code by xcode coused the table view controller to flush the content.